# How to build a JAR for an android project

Tags: android, maven

I am working on a small project to allow cookies to persist. I want to make the project as a JAR so other developers can use it in there project. At the moment I am able to build the project as an APKLIB however this seems unnecessary as the resources are not needed. If I change the packaging to JAR I get the follow error when building

Results :

> Tests in error:
>   shouldAddCookie(com.doward.persistantcookietest.PersistantCookieStoreTest):
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: caught an exception while obtaining
>   a class file for com.doward.persistantcookies.R
>   shouldClearAllCookies(com.doward.persistantcookietest.PersistantCookieStoreTest):
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: caught an exception while obtaining
>   a class file for com.doward.persistantcookies.R
>   shouldClearExpired(com.doward.persistantcookietest.PersistantCookieStoreTest):
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: caught an exception while obtaining
>   a class file for com.doward.persistantcookies.R

The POM looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.doward</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistantcookiestore</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>persistantcookies</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2_r2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just build a JAR file from `.class` files and no resources e.g. no XML files releating to layouts, values, colours etc then you can do so from the command line:

`jar -cvf <filenameorjar.jar> <files to be included>`

Example:

`jar -cvf cookiepersist.jar com/*`

This will create a jar file in the present working directory and include all the `.class` files from the directory `com` in the present working directory.

Comment: thanks, nice to know. But I was hoping to use maven to do this so I can automate the build process and also make it avalible for other developers to use

Answer (score 0):

If you have a andorid project and you wish to use the same in another project you can make the project as a library project and refer the same in another Android project. This can include your resources also.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

You export your utility classes that do not refer to resources in android ie pure java classes. If you use eclipse you can have a look at the tutorial below

http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/01/creating-jar-file-in-eclipse.html

Comment: I am trying to do this with maven. I am using sharedpreferences to store the cookies so there are dependencies on android classes also

Comment: Ok. Generally we use eclipse as a tool. However i have not used maven.

Comment: well I am hoping to make this available to other developers. Maven is the easiest way to use other libraries within a project. Also I want the unit tests to be run before the build